# How to make an awaiter for MyFuture class to use in Asio with CoroutineTS?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++-coroutine

1. I have `my_future` class (didn't insert here as it is quite big) and I want to use it with CoroutineTS and Asio.
2. I am using BoostAsio 1.66 version (quite old but I can't change it easily).
3. I tried to write the first prototype of awaiter and overloadered `co_await` like (`my_future.h` file):

```
// Dummy class
class my_promise
{
public:
    void set(T){};
};

// Dummy class
template <typename T>
class my_future
{
public:
    my_future(my_promise<T>)
    {
    }

    T get()
    {
        return T{};
    };
};

template <typename T>
class future_awaiter
{
    using value_type = typename my_future<T>::value_type;

public:
    explicit future_awaiter(my_future<T> f) : f_(std::move(f))
    {
    }

    bool await_ready()
    {
        return f_.ready();
    }

    void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h)
    {
        f_.then([h](auto) mutable { h.resume(); });
    }

    value_type await_resume()
    {
        return f_.get();
    }

private:
    my_future<T> f_;
};

template <typename T>
auto operator co_await(my_future<T> f)
{
    return future_awaiter(std::move(f));
}
```

And tried to use it in a code like this (`main.cpp` file):

```
#include "my_future.h"

#include <boost/asio/experimental/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <experimental/coroutine>

boost::asio::experimental::awaitable<void> coro()
{
    my_promise<int> p;
    my_future<int> f(p);
    p.set(42);
    co_await f;
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::co_spawn(io, coro, boost::asio::experimental::detached);
    io.run();

    return 0;
}
```

In this case I get a compilation error `No matching member function for call to 'await_transform'`. And I understand why this is happening: because `promise_type` under `awaitable` mechanism has `await_transform` methods which are trying to be applied to `my_future`, but there is no overload.

4. My final goal is to run my coroutines, containing `my_future` with custom Awaiter on `io_service`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about the actual Coroutine TS, or the C++20 coroutine feature? Because they're not the same, and I don't think Asio works with the TS.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I mean C++ coroutines